# Superscript/subscript fonts different from body font

Tags: fonts, subscripts, superscripts

The following minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
10$^5$ and CO$_2$.
\end{document}
```

produces the following:

[image]

The superscript and subscript fonts are different from the body font. Why is this happening, and how can I ensure that those fonts are the same as the body font?

Comment: Those are the fonts used in math mode. There are packages like `siunitx` or `chemformula` that can help you with a consistent appearance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In my view, it's abusing the math environment to use it only to make superscript and subscript numbers in a context that is not math. So I would use `\textsuperscript` and `\textsubscript` instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
10\textsuperscript{5} and CO\textsubscript{2}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I agree completely with your first sentence, but 10^5 *is* maths, and should (if not using siunitx's `\num` -- which I wouldn't here) be written as `$10^5$`.  In this case `$\mathsf{10^5}$` is appropriate.

Comment: Note that `fixltx2e` is an obsolete package. Use `changes`.

Comment: @ChrisH I don't fully agree with that. `10^5` is in of itself not math - I consider it to be just a number. The context should decide. To me, a sentence like "There are 10^5 CO_2 particles in this sample" is no more math than a sentence "I am 20 years old". They're both just numbers in a sentence telling us the amount of particles and years. If the number is part of a mathematical operation, then that's another story: `$10^5 - 1 = 99999$` is math just like `$20 - 1 = 19$` is.

Comment: @Fran, true but it's made obsolete so recently that I think most users probably need it here. I'll wait until after the release of texlive2015 to consider it obsolete.

Answer (score 6):

Those are the fonts used in math mode. Using `mathsf` you can switch to a sans serif math font. On the other hand, there are packages like `siunitx` and `chemformula` that ease the input significantly.

[image: sabrewolfyMathSf]

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\begin{document}
10$^5$ and CO$_2$.\par
10$^\mathsf{5}$ and CO$_\mathsf{2}$.\par
\num{1e5} and \ch{CO2}.\par
\end{document}
```

Comment: With siunitx, `\num{e5}` works if you don't want the `1x` part.

Comment: @TonioElGringo Yeah, but the syntax is very powerful and should be shown ;-)

Answer (score 5):

A variant with package `siunitx` for numbers and units (with font detection) and `mhchem` for chemical formulas:

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\num{e5} and \ce{CO2}.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

Use `sfmath` package [here](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/sfmath).

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{sfmath}
\begin{document}
10$^5$ and CO$_2$.
\end{document}
```

[image]